# How to temporarily block all macros from running and edit xlsm file with VBScript?

Tags: vbscript, macros, xlsm

I have xlsm file which I need to edit. However, macros there block my script from editing. My code is following:

```
xlsm_file_name = "webADI_template_Bankbuchungen_GL.xlsm"
'opening xlsm file and setting readonly to false
set xlobj = createobject("Excel.Application")
set excel_file = xlobj.workbooks.open("C:\Users\oleynikov nikolay\Desktop\VBS Automation Scripts\processed_data\Excel Datei\"&xlsm_file_name, readonly=false)
'making changes invisible for the user
excel_file.application.enableevents = false
xlobj.Visible = false
'defining the sheet where we will be inserting our data into 
set excel_sheet = excel_file.worksheets(1)
excel_sheet.cells(13,4).value = "EUR"
excel_file.application.enableevents = TRUE
xlobj.DisplayAlerts = FALSE
excel_file.save
```

At the end of the day, no values are added. This happens because double clicking on the cell runs the macro. I need to disable this macro, insert necessary values and then enable the macros again.

Is there a possibility to do it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (it seems it should work):

Returns or sets an MsoAutomationSecurity constant that represents the security mode that Microsoft Excel uses when programmatically opening files. Read/write.

MsoAutomationSecurity can be one of these MsoAutomationSecurity constants:

- msoAutomationSecurityByUI. Uses the security setting specified in the Security dialog box.
- msoAutomationSecurityForceDisable. Disables all macros in all files opened programmatically without showing any security alerts.

**VB**

```
Sub Security() 
Dim secAutomation As MsoAutomationSecurity 
secAutomation = Application.AutomationSecurity 
Application.AutomationSecurity = msoAutomationSecurityForceDisable 
Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen).Show 
Application.AutomationSecurity = secAutomation 
End Sub
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.automationsecurity

Comment: I tried, nothing happens. The file gets updated but without newly written values in the excel. I solved the problem with adding dynamic self destructing module VBA code which inserts values obtained in VBScript, and then deletes itself